# Setting an iPhone alarm in code?

Tags: iphone, xcode, alarm

Is it possible to set an alarm & alarm description for the iPhone's alarm clock application WITHIN my application code? So for example, set a 7:00am alarm with a description 'make coffee" in code. So when the user exits my program, if they enter iPhones clock application it will have a 7am alarm set?, any responses will be greatly appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't [`Event Kit`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) serve your purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Nope—your application is sandboxed by the system and cannot access or modify other apps’ data. You can create your own scheduled notifications, however, using the `UILocalNotification` class; if you Google that, you’ll find plenty of examples of how to create alarm-like alerts that way.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, ill check your suggestion. I had thought there might be some tie in with a uiapplication sharedapplication function to override the sandbox but i guess not, many thanks.

Comment: Actually UILocalNotification is PERFECT, thanks, it basically provides the same functionality.